# Reverse proxy with nginx

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy, nat, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to use reverse proxy with nginx to redirect/translate IP and port to some other IP and port. I was able to do that using the following code snippet inside http block of nginx.conf:

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  13.88.1.1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://13.68.1.1:8888/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        } # end location
    } # end server
```

Now the problem is that this is only usable for http requests. I have a scenario where I need to run an executable like 'uw.exe 13.88.1.1:80'. This is getting translated to 'uw.exe [http://13.68.1.1:8888'](http://13.68.1.1:8888%27) but I want it to get translated to 'uw.exe 13.68.1.1:8888'. That is without the http because my app won't work with http. Does anybody know any simple solution to do that, preferably with nginx itself?

***Update***: This is no longer needed and cannot test it anymore. Thanks guys for chiming in. :)

Comment: Then what protocol does your app accept?

Comment: I tried to use UDP but then I was able to reach the actual server but not getting any response back obviously as UDP is just one way. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am open to use anything else other than nginx as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://13.88.1.1:8888/;
    }
}
```